# FromAssembliesMatching overwrites explicitly set bindings

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-conventions

Is there a way to combine a call to FromAssembliesMatching to set up most interfaces automatically and some explicit bindings? I have the following code that should set all ISomething to Something automatically, and then set up a specific constructor for the IUnitOfWork interface where the concrete implementation accepts two bools as arguments:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("*.dll").SelectAllClasses()
        .InNamespaces("MyNamespace").BindDefaultInterface());
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToConstructor(x => new UnitOfWork(true, false));
```

However, when I try to call TryGet like this I get a null back:

```
kernel.TryGet<MyNamespace.IUnitOfWork>()
```

It works fine when I switch the order around and call Excluding for the UnitOfWork implementation explicitly on the second call:

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToConstructor(x => new UnitOfWork(true, false));
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("*.dll").SelectAllClasses()
      .InNamespaces("MyNamespace").Excluding(typeof(UnitOfWork))
      .BindDefaultInterface());
```

Reversing the order, or leaving out the call to Excluding results in null again when I try to resolve an instance of an IUnitOfWork.

What's the proper way to combine automatic matching with explicit configuration? I am using Ninject 3.2.0.0 and Ninject.Extensions.Conventions 3.2.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways to handle your situation, one you've already found:

- `Excluding<>` a type from the convention.

  - Advantage: This is agnostic to the sequence of your "manual" and your convention bindings.
  - Disadvantage: you need to refer to special cases in two places, in the convention and in the "manual" binding
- using `Rebind<IUnitOfWork>` instead of Bind.

  - Advantage: you don't need to refer to the special case in two places.
  - Disadvantage: This only works if you perform the convention binding before doing the `Rebind`.

Of course you could also add an attribute to all types which should be excluded from conventions and adapt your conventions accordingly. But i doubt that that would be any better.

By the way, one could imagine something like extending the convention to check whether a binding for that type already exists, and only creating a new binding if it doesn't. Besides the obvious complications with multi- and contextual-bindings, ninject has no easy access to check whether a binding for an "implementation" type already exists. All there is is `IKernel.GetBindings(Type serviceType)`. And due to some internals this can't be changed easily.